# Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi friends i am gettting this error my query is 
i tried by applying / after declaration of package

```
Create or Replace Package PACKAGE1 as
    TYPE Page is REF CURSOR;
    Procedure GetPage(PageSize IN int, PageIndex IN INT, PageData OUT Page);
End PACKAGE1;

CREATE OR REPLACE package body PACKAGE1 as
    Procedure GetPage(PageSize IN int, PageIndex IN INT, PageData OUT Page) IS
        FirstIndex int;
        LastIndex int;
    BEGIN
        LastIndex := PageSize * (PageIndex +1);
        FirstIndex := LastIndex - PageSize +1;
        Open PageData for  Select * from (  select a.*, rownum as rnum from (select * from MyTable) a where rownum <= LastIndex ) where rnum >= FirstIndex;
    END GetPage;
END PACKAGE1;
```

Comment: Have you tried `/` followed by new line?

Comment: As San mentioned, you're missing a / between the package header and the package body.

Comment: yes frank ,san i tried

Comment: after / trying this i am gettting this error::Error(14,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

Comment: Where are you running this - which client, and with which command? It needs to be run as a script in SQL Developer, for example, rather than as a statement. Did you put the `/` at the start of a new line?

Comment: i am running as a script and i kept / at start of new line

Comment: is it  happening because of this code is failing: Procedure GetPage(PageSize IN int, PageIndex IN INT, PageData OUT Page) IS
        FirstIndex int;
        LastIndex int;
    BEGIN
        LastIndex := PageSize * (PageIndex +1);
        FirstIndex := LastIndex - PageSize +1;
        Open PageData for  Select * from (  select a.*, rownum as rnum from (select * from MyTable) a where rownum <= LastIndex ) where rnum >= FirstIndex;
    END GetPage;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commentators pointed, `'/'` is need for both `CREATE` statements.

```
Create or Replace Package PACKAGE1 as
    TYPE Page is REF CURSOR;
    Procedure GetPage(PageSize IN int, PageIndex IN INT, PageData OUT Page);
End PACKAGE1;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE package body PACKAGE1 as
    Procedure GetPage(PageSize IN int, PageIndex IN INT, PageData OUT Page) IS
        FirstIndex int;
        LastIndex int;
    BEGIN
        LastIndex := PageSize * (PageIndex +1);
        FirstIndex := LastIndex - PageSize +1;
        Open PageData for  Select * from (  select a.*, rownum as rnum from (select * from MyTable) a where rownum <= LastIndex ) where rnum >= FirstIndex;
    END GetPage;
END PACKAGE1;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

create new package and add declaration

```
Create or Replace Package PACKAGE1 as
    TYPE Page is REF CURSOR;
    Procedure GetPage(PageSize IN int, PageIndex IN INT, PageData OUT Page);
End PACKAGE1;
```

then create body by right clicking package AND SELECT ADD PACKAGE

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE package body PACKAGE1 as
        Procedure GetPage(PageSize IN int, PageIndex IN INT, PageData OUT Page) IS
            FirstIndex int;
            LastIndex int;
        BEGIN
            LastIndex := PageSize * (PageIndex +1);
            FirstIndex := LastIndex - PageSize +1;
            Open PageData for  Select * from (  select a.*, rownum as rnum from (select * from MyTable) a where rownum <= LastIndex ) where rnum >= FirstIndex;
        END GetPage;
    END PACKAGE1;
```

then compile code

execute using following line of code

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec paginate(20,1, :rc);
print rc;
```

Comment: Pankaj, it's the same, that I mentioned. Every '/' completes the DDL.

Comment: You again unaccepted my answer?? :( My answer is the core behaviour of compiling PL/SQL blocks.